# Phython Selenium - Inspect Element followed by action - Instagram Automation

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to Python and was looking at Instagram automation by writing a application to like an Instagram post using selenium, I have manged to login and access the URL of the post I want to like, however to avoid 'unliking' it by clicking on it if it's previously liked already I wanted to implement a check first.

Using the inspect element I have been able to identify the class for the like button and could see that there are several attributes I could use:

The class name itself which is 'wpO6b' after trying multiple posts (however I am not entirely sure if it's the right approach). Moreover upon printing the attributes of this class, there seems to be several attributes that seems to be useful here like **svg aria-label=** and **fill=** (the values differing when a post is liked or not liked).

I am able to print the attribute, however proceeding further is a challenge and would appreciate some help in using the innerHTML output to further write an if loop or if-else loop etc. to check if the parameters match that of a 'unliked' post and then run the value.click() to click and like the post else move on to the next URL in the list.

**Code**

```
drv.get(ur1)
elm = drv.find_element_by_class_name("wpO6b")
print(elm.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

**Output:**

```
<svg aria-label="Unlike" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#ed4956" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M35.3 35.6c-9.2 8.2-9.8 8.9-11.3 8.9s-2.1-.7-11.3-8.9C6.5 30.1.5 25.6.5 17.8.5 9.9 6.4 3.5 13.7 3.5 20.8 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s3.2-5.3 10.3-5.3c7.3 0 13.2 6.4 13.2 14.3 0 7.8-6.1 12.3-12.2 17.8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
```

Comment: you seems to have answer in your question. what is the challenge in checking the attribute aria-label using a if statement ? is it not working?

Comment: I am not able to get the output into a variable, like var1 = (elm.get_attribute("innerHTML")) so that I can work on the output using an if statement. Else if I can run it on the print function that would be great if you could advise.

Comment: did you try elm.get_attribute("aria-label") ? . This should return - 'Unlike'

Comment: Since innerHTML returns all the attribute as a string, you can also check if the string contains the "Unlike".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, elm.get_attribute("aria-label") has thrown an error. The string suggestion, will give it a shot but I am not sure how to get the output print(elm.get_attribute("innerHTML")) into a string which I can use or put it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Used this and it worked, it checks if the button has the fill color for unlike and then likes the post or it continues to the next link:

```
inst_url = open('links.txt', 'r')

def link_click():
    sleep(randint(1, 2))
    for urls in inst_url:
        drv.get(urls)
        elm = drv.find_element_by_class_name('wpO6b')
        elem = (elm.get_property("innerHTML"))
        if "#262626" in elem:
            value = drv.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button')
            value.click()
```